# Optional dependency in SBT

Tags: sbt

Maven has the [optional dependency](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) concept. Search of the SBT documentation for optional dependencies finds only ["However, sometimes we have optional dependencies for special features."](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Using-Sonatype.html).

How can I declare an optional dependency in SBT?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately [SBT documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Scopes.html) doesn't list all available scopes that map to Ivy Configurations, but the source code does: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/ivy/src/main/scala/sbt/Configuration.scala

You can do this in the same way you scope a dependency for test, runtime or provided scope.

```
libraryDependencies += "group id" % "artifact id" % "version" % "optional"
```

or

```
libraryDependencies += "group id" % "artifact id" % "version" % Optional
```